# Simplest example for sending post data via links in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

Starting with Zend and I´d like to know what is the simplest way of sending POST data to another page, not by forms, but by some link in my view instead. Thanks :)

Comment: `Zend_Http_Client` - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html#zend.http.client.raw_post_data

Comment: but how would we implement it to send the data via some link ?

Comment: Are you trying to POST to your own site or other sites on the net?  Links can't post (unless you use JavaScript or make the link do something on the server).  That leaves the question of what data will be posted and where does it come from?

Comment: to my own site ... will POST simple strings to populate a form that updates the data

Answer (score 0):

You can't send POST data through a link. At least not through a normal link. Link can only carry GET data.

If you need to send POST over a link it's most certainly a design flaw.

If you're 100% sure, that you need it, you can do that [using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) and onclick event. It`s not possible to do it without javascript. Other option would be to send it using form with hidden fields with single submit button visible - that would even work without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Normal hyperlinks in HTML are sent with GET requests and are not supposed to change the state of the resource being accessed.  This is known as being [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Idempotent_methods_and_web_applications).  You can repeat the request over and over, and the result of each succeeding request to the same URL is the same as the first one.

POST requests don't have this restriction and are intended for when the user needs to change something (such as creating a new resource.)

It's not possible to send a POST request via a normal HTML link.  And even if you find a way, it breaks an almost universal expectation that web users have.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Maybe there's a better way.

But to answer your question, you could use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to capture the "click" event and make it do a POST request:

```
$('.my-link').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var data = {};
    $.post(url, data, function() {
        window.alert('success!');
    });
    return false;
});
```

If your URL has any query parameters, i.e. "?foo=bar&baz=bum", then you'd probably need to strip them off of the URL and pass them as a second parameter to the [$.post() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).  This is left as an exercise for the reader.  ;-)